# Google Sheets: Formula not working

Tags: worksheet-function, google-drive, google-spreadsheets

I have the following formula below:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D5),MULTIPLY(C5:D5),"0.00")
```

I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong here or if I even can (I don't know much about Google Sheets formulas at all....) but basically, I want E5 to equal C5*D5, and if D5 is empty, I want E5 to equal 0. any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance all!!!

Comment: You must swap operands 2 and 3.

Comment: That did it! Thanks Akina!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D5),"0.00",C5*D5)
```

There is not a `MULTIPLY` function, so use simply operator `*`.

---

*Note:*

Consider changing the **string** `"0.00"`  to the **number** `0`, to avoid problems with involving this cell in other calculations.

Comment: Had to flip the multiplication and 0, but that worked perfectly!!

Comment: Oh, you're right, I'm going to fix it in my answer. Consider changing the **string** `"0.00"`  to the **number** `0`, too, to avoid problems with involving this cell into other calculation.